# Having trouble finding roots/factorizing a cubic equation

Tags: factoring, cubics

I've been trying to find a method that can work for any cubic equation, but I can't seem to find one.
Right now, I'm trying to find the roots/ factorize the following equation: $x^3-5x^2+3x+9 = 0$. I've tried the method to see what's common in both, but does not simplify correctly. $x^2(x-5)+3(x+3)=0$

The answers are 1 and 3 with a multiplicity of 2, though I don't know how it was attained. How can I factor that equation?

Comment: You could use the rational roots theorem to get one rational root and then use polynomial division to reduce it to a quadratic.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to just check $-1, 0, 1$ manually before going any further ($-1, 0, 1$ being the easiest numbers to check manually).  Professors/ textbook authors seem to love the solutions $-1$ and $1$.  You'll notice that one of them works for your equation.

Comment: No, $1$ is clearly not a root, check it for yourself. I suspect that you meant $-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a flow chart for factoring cubics for you.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! very helpful!

Comment: No problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you must searching for divisors of $9$ and we find $-1,3$ thus we have $$(x-3)^2(x+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with polynomial equation with integer coefficients, always try $1$ first.

That is not a solution, so try $-1$.

$$(-1)^3-5*(-1)^2+3*(-1)+9=-1-5*1+3*(-1)+9=-1-5-3+9=0$$

So $x+1$ is a factor of $x^3-5x^2+3x+9$

Now, use synthetic division:

$$x^2-6x+9$$

Before we go applying the rational root theorem, nevermind the quadratic formula, Note that 9 is a perfect square, and also note that 6 is twice the square root of 9. We thus have a perfect square polynomial, and it can be factored into

$$(x-3)^2$$

With $3$ as the other solution of $x^3-5x^2+3x+9=0$

The polynomial in fully factored form is

$$(x+1)(x-3)^2$$